# Animation of a small texture gets slow when pasted on a larger texture

Tags: opengl

I want to animate a square box with a texture on it (that is a .raw image file). My background also consists of a much larger sized box and also with an image over it.

I am using the timer() function to animate the box. The problem is that as i keep on increasing the background image , my animation gets slower . how can i increase its speed ..?

raw_texture_load

```
  GLuint raw_texture_load1( const char * filename, int width , int height)
  {
  GLuint texture;
  unsigned char *data;
  FILE * file;

  // open texture data
  file = fopen( filename, "rb" );
  if ( file == NULL ) return 0;

  // allocate buffer

  data= (unsigned char*) malloc(width * height*3);

 // read texture data
 fread( data, width * height*3 , 1, file );
 fclose( file );

 // allocate a texture name
 glGenTextures( 1, &texture );

 // select our current texture
 glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );

// select modulate to mix texture with color for shading
glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE );

// when texture area is small, bilinear filter the closest MIP map
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
               GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST );
// when texture area is large, bilinear filter the first MIP map
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );

// if wrap is true, the texture wraps over at the edges (repeat)
//       ... false, the texture ends at the edges (clamp)
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
                GL_REPEAT );
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
                GL_REPEAT );

// build our texture MIP maps
gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, width,
height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data );

// free buffer
free( data );

return texture;

}
```

main code

```
 .
 .
 GLuint texture1 ;
 GLuint texture2 ;
 GLuint raw_texture_load1( const char * filename, int width , int height );
 GLuint raw_texture_load2( const char * filename, int width , int height );

 int refreshMills = 10 ;

 .
 .
 .
 void initGL() {
  glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
  texture1 = raw_texture_load1("level.raw", 700, 700);
  texture2 = raw_texture_load2("mario2.raw", 100, 100);
}


 void display()
 {
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   // Clear the color buffer
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);     // To operate on Model-View matrix
glLoadIdentity();
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D , texture1);
glBegin(GL_QUADS) ;
  glTexCoord2d(0,1);glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0);
  glTexCoord2d(1,1);glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, 0.0);
  glTexCoord2d(1,0);glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  glTexCoord2d(0,0);glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  glEnd() ;
  glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glPopMatrix() ;


     glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D , texture2) ;
    glBegin(GL_QUADS); 
   glTexCoord2d(0,1);glVertex3f(0.2+move, 0.0, 0.0);
  glTexCoord2d(1,1);glVertex3f(0.0+move, 0.0, 0.0);
  glTexCoord2d(1,0);glVertex3f(0.0+move, 0.2, 0.0);
  glTexCoord2d(0,0);glVertex3f(0.2+move, 0.2, 0.0);
  glEnd();  
  glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glPopMatrix() ;
  glutSwapBuffers() ;

  }



  void Timer(int value)
   {
   glutPostRedisplay();      // Post re-paint request to activate display()
   glutTimerFunc(refreshMills, Timer, 0); // next Timer call milliseconds later
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that as i keep on increasing the background image , my animation gets slower. how can i increase its speed?

The keyword here is *fillrate*. The larger your background, the more pixels the GPU has to transfer from and to its RAM. Because fillrate is so variable, using a static timer will not yield good results. The proper way is to measure the time between frames rendered and use that as base for the animation.

Comment: i understood what you told. thanks..but can you explain where i need to do necessary changes in my code . ?

Comment: i am creating 2 files , raw_texture_load1 & raw_texture_load2 , to import 2 different images . can i optimize that and use just a single one..??

Comment: @user2208784. Of course you can (and should) use a single function for that, but in your code this is one-time initialization and has zero influence on the rendering performance. To time your animation just store the current system time with ms precision at the beginning of the display function. Each call of the display function take the time difference and use this as input for the animation progress, i.e. your update of `move`.

Answer (score 0):

As datenwolf already pointed out, your performance is fillrate-limited.

How "sharp" does level.raw have to appear? If (like most backgrounds) you can get by without too much detail, then scale it down from 700x700 to 512x512. If you can get by with 256x256, try that too.

This smaller power-of-two sized image *should* allow better texture cache performance, improving your fillrate.

Comment: yeah i tried that too. I used a 100x100 image.When i kept my background small it worked fine.. But as i enlarged background , the problem continued .